# В каких случая лучше применять Template Method, а в каких Strategy

Tags: ооп, шаблоны-проектирования

В каких случая лучше применять Template Method, а в каких Strategy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте паттерн стратегия, когда:
    имеется много родственных классов, отличающихся только поведением. Стратегия позволяет сконфигурировать класс, задав одно из возможных поведений;
    вам нужно иметь несколько разных вариантов алгоритма. Например, можно определить два варианта алгоритма, один из которых требует больше времени, а другой - больше памяти.Стратегии разрешается применять, когда варианты алгоритмов реализованы в виде иерархии классов.
    в алгоритме содержаться данные о которых клиент не должен знать. Используйте паттерн стратегия, чтобы не раскрывать сложные, специфичные для алгоритма структуры данных;
    в классе определено много поведений, что представлено разветвленными условными операторами. В этом случае проще перенести код из ветвей в отдельные классы стратегий.

Паттерн шаблонный метод следует использовать:
    чтобы однократно использовать инвариантные части алгоритма, оставляя реализацию изменяющего поведения на усмотрение подклассов;
    когда нужно вычленить и локализовать в одном классе поведение, общее для всех подклассов, дабы избежать дублирования кода;
    для управления расширениями подклассов. Можно определить шаблонный метод так, что он будет вызывать операции-зацепки в определенных точках, разрешив тем самым расширение только в этих точках.

подробнее можете прочитать например здесь https://systems-ez.ru/index.php/ru/patterns/template-method